# Frame objects in polar plot with Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, tkinter, frame

Is there a way to frame a group of data points in a polar plot?

Currently I use the `add_patch(Rectangle(...))`, but it does not fit really well. Especially if the data points are not horizontal in a row (see picture).

[image: exmaple1] [image: example2]